# Is there any forwarding benefit to ask equal?

Tags: teachers

Or is it just to maintain ones home, dwelling, without any fruits toward liberation?

Given one is in debt, is it wise to seek advices by those in debts or wouln't it be smarter to ask those having left this state?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the question.

There are people who understand the canon better than I do and who can help me to read and understand it, so it makes sense to ask that sort of question.

Also there are people who have experience of different teachers, doctrines, and/or practices, perhaps it makes sense to ask about that kind of experience too.

So maybe you're right, i.e. "no, it doesn't make sense to ask an equal -- instead it makes more sense to ask people who know better, or who know different".

See also what [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/9424/254) says about "conceit", though, i.e. beware of thinking that one is "equal" etc.

Comment: What does that mean in regard of liberation, thought one might search for such interested in Dhamma?

Answer (score 2):

Any teacher knows that the best way to improve your understanding of a topic you think to have mastered is to try to teach it to someone else. Only then, through your student, you will see where your own lack of understanding lies.

No one is at the same level in the same topics as you are in the path. No one understands the same topics the same way as you do. No one faces the exact same struggles as you do.

Just exchanging ideas among equals, with periodic access to a more advanced teacher or source to answer and explore your doubts, is perhaps the best and easiest way to advance.

Answer (score 2):

The teacher must have the following qualifications according to the [Udayi Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an05/an05.159.than.html). There are no requirements here towards being enlightened.

> "It's not easy to teach the Dhamma to others, Ananda. The Dhamma
>   should be taught to others only when five qualities are established
>   within the person teaching. Which five?
>
> "(1) The Dhamma should be taught with the thought, 'I will speak
>   step-by-step.'
>
> "(2) The Dhamma should be taught with the thought, 'I will speak
>   explaining the sequence [of cause & effect].'
>
> "(3) The Dhamma should be taught with the thought, 'I will speak out
>   of compassion.'
>
> "(4) The Dhamma should be taught with the thought, 'I will speak not
>   for the purpose of material reward.'
>
> "(5) The Dhamma should be taught with the thought, 'I will speak
>   without hurting myself or others.' (see Note)
>
> "It's not easy to teach the Dhamma to others, Ananda. The Dhamma
>   should be taught to others only when these five qualities are
>   established within the person teaching."
>
> Note:
>   According to the Commentary, "hurting oneself" means exalting oneself.
>   "Hurting others" means putting other people down.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good question Samana Johann…. Given that one is in ‘samsaric’ debt, it is wise to seek advice from those having left this state.  This is about the bondages and attachments that we keep making towards other living beings and other.  Our lives and existence are based on constantly getting into debt and then paying off debts. When we get into debt, the nature keeps track of that via kammic energy. We are reborn to pay debts. This is another way of looking at the cycle of rebirths. If one is not aware of this fact, during a given lifetime, only a little debt is paid off, but a lot more gets added.  We become indebted to other living beings or to the “world as a whole” as a result.

One who walks this Noble Eightfold Path has to make sure to relieve oneself of this bondage. Otherwise one cannot go far in this Path. In this beginning-less sansara, we have been indebted to unbelievably many beings. Thus, we have to know how to properly transfer the merits that we’ve accumulated to all beings.  Also, whenever we have done something harmful to another being in this beginning-less sansara, we have become indebted to that being, unless we start seeking forgiveness from such. One needs to do this with sincerity, truly understanding the suffering caused by one’s actions to others.

Then there’s this other aspect, where others become indebted to you because of the good deeds that you have done in this beginning-less sansara to other. So you should know how to free others from this indebtedness to you, so that you become free from ALL bondages (the state of being bound) if you are to walk this Noble Eightfold Path.